# Issue with Google's edge TPU compiler

Tags: artificial-intelligence, robotics, tpu, google-coral

I tried to install edge TPU compiler on my raspberrypi 3b+ but apparently it is no longer supported on 32bit. Can I install compiler on a 64bit machine, compile my code, turn it into a code readable by the edge tpu and bring this code back and run it on my raspberry pi? Or will there be conflict of some sort?

Comment: Assuming that you have connected a TPU device(Like USB Accelerator) with your RPI. You can run the compiled model on that RPI. Please see the requirements at : https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#requirements.
It's just that the compiler cannot be installed on a 32-bit machine but the output (.tflite) format can be executed on TPU connected to a ARMv7 32-bit machine.

Comment: What I did was I used an online compiler which let me connect compile the code successfully. If anyone is stuck please let me know I will provide the link!

Answer (score 0):

- As far as application goes:
  You can write your application code on the rpi. The code that you compiles on an x86-64 machine won't be executable on the rpi due to architecture differences. Unless you are using a cross compiler.
- Now on the edgetpu compiler:
  The edgetpu compiler can only be installed on the `x86_64` machine, although since the format of the model is the same for all platform (flat buffer), you can use the same model compiled on the `x86_64` platform on your rpi just fine!